# Interpreting daily and total spend for UK employee's international travel expense

Tags: united-kingdom, company-policy, travel, expenses, language

I am reviewing the wording in an international travel expense policy for UK employees, and the following excerpt is unclear to me:

> Total spend for the duration of travel should not exceed <amount> per day.

Does this mean:

- the total spend should not exceed *amount* x *days*
- the daily spend should not exceed the *amount*
- both of the above

Comment: Ask your HR or the person / manager in control of the policy or payment.

Comment: Very, very related: [Accidentally spent much more than the food allowance on a business trip](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187807/accidentally-spent-much-more-than-the-food-allowance-on-a-business-trip/). (Also a very good example of why you shouldn't trust the accepted answer on questions)

Comment: I asked to see if I should suggest the terms need to be clarified. I have spoken to the accounts team and my interpretation was correct so will not be out of pocket, thankfully.

Comment: @NSGoat, No, the sentence looks perfectly clear to me, so I'm not sure how it could be made any clearer.

Comment: I will take a wild guess and say neither the writer, nor audience of the policy is a lawyer or English teacher. Is there a virtual paper shortage, that forces you to keep it that short? Why not make it two sentences and add an example to make it crystal clear what is meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"£80 per day" means you are free to spend £70 one day and £90 the next day. As long as you don't exceed the number of days, multiplied by £80, over the whole trip.

"£80 on each day" means exactly that. You can spend £80 today even if you saved money on other days.

(PS At many companies you can spend as much as you like, but they will only refund you in this example £80 per day. If you spend more, it will just come out of your own pocket. So for ten days someone will tell you "You gave us receipts for $1,021, and we pay you £800, no problem". Don't do this with a company credit card. )

Answer (score 9):

Ask. Getting this wrong can lead to you losing money, or you not spending what you are entitled to.

In some places you have to specify your daily spend on your expense report. Thus being frugal one one day doesn't allow you to go over on other days.

Ask about the requirement for receipts for food and other incidentals. Requiring receipts is a sign that you can only claim what you spend. And they will impose a per day limit. Even if they require receipts they still might only look at the total for the whole trip. So ask detailed questions.

Also ask about the first and the last days of the trip. For US government employees, the first and last day have lower limits. I have worked for companies that limited you based on the meals involved, and others used a set percent. Again getting this wrong could cause you to lose money.

Answer (score 2):

**The statement means that the total you spend on a trip should not be more than <amount> times the length of the trip in days.**

It is probably phrased like this because if they write "You should not spend more than <amount>? per day" some people might think you are not allowed to spend more than <amount> on any given day, and that's not what they mean.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, it means that if your trip is 7 days, and your amount is £100. Then your total spend for the entire trip should be less than (7*100) = £700.

I would also guess it doesn't include the cost of travel to/from your destination.

But this is one of those situations where you shouldn't make guesses. Just ask HR (or whoever's in charge of travel expenses) for clarification so you can make sure you follow the rules correctly.

Comment: My last job before I retired was with expenses policy for a large UK public sector organisation. Maximum hotel expenses were £120 per night in London, £100 elsewhere. This did NOT mean a person who booked and paid for a two night stay in London could claim £130 for the first night and £110 the second night. They would only get £120 + £110.  At one time, we could amend overclaims and pay the reduced amount, but we changed to rejecting the whole claim and requiring a new one. They were free to use our corporate booking partner, who get bulk rates, and they didn't have to spend and then claim.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding would match the first interpretation. It doesn't really matter to a reasonable organization whether you eat frugally on one day of your travel and have a visit to an expensive restaurant on the next day as long as the sum does not exceed `daily_amount * number_of_days`.

Of course, organizations and the people representing them aren't always reasonable, so the best bet is to ask them what they mean and whether your interpretation is correct.